# HQL query help to return latest date from mssql db

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have this HQL query which returns all the product in the table. But I want to get only the products with latest price date not the old one too. How can I do it.

```
String select = "SELECT p FROM  ProductPricing p where p.productId.supplierId.id=:id"; // nested condition based on the FK productpricing -> product -> supplier

    Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery(select);
    query.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(dsRequest.getFieldValue("supplier").toString()));

    List<ProductPricing> models = query.list();

    for (int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++)
    {
        if (models.get(i).getProductId() != null)
        {
            models.get(i).getProductId().getProductCode();
            models.get(i).getProductId().getBrandName();
            models.get(i).getPurchasePrice();
            System.out.println(models.get(i).getProductId().getBrandName());
        }

    }
```

My ProductPrice table looks like this. now this HQL query of mine returns all the records.But I just want it to return the record with the price Date which is latest i.e. id 2 and 4 for those productID

```
id priceDate                   purchasePrice salesPrice consumerPrice productID description 

1  2012-11-15 00:00:00         1000          1200       1500          1         qwqw        
2  2013-11-16 00:00:00         1600          1800       2100          1         new price   
3  2012-10-15 00:00:00         1600          1500       1600          2         erere   
4  2013-11-02 00:00:00         1600          1900       3400          2         new price
```

Comment: whether you are maintaining separate column for latest price

Comment: what do you mean??.my ProductPricing table looks like this
 
    productPricing (id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    priceDate    DATETIME, 
    purchasePrice FLOAT(53), salesPrice FLOAT(53), consumerPrice FLOAT(53), productID BIGINT, description NVARCHAR(255)

Comment: please help,I will appreciate it

Comment: I having the SQL is that enough. I 'll give you the HQL later

Answer (score 0):

This is return last thirty date pricing

```
String select = "SELECT p.salesPrice FROM  ProductPricing p where p.productId.supplierId.id=:id ORDER BY p.priceDate desc"; 
Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery(select);
query.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(dsRequest.getFieldValue("supplier").toString()));

List<ProductPricing> models = query.list();
```

Filter the result in your business logic, I think that's how you db is designed(one-to-many relation)

This is the SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE `testspring`.`pricing`(     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,     `priceDate` DATETIME ,     `purchasePrice` INT ,     `salesPrice` INT ,     `consumerPrice` INT ,     `productID` INT ,     `description` VARCHAR(255) ,     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  );

INSERT INTO `testspring`.`pricing`(`id`,`priceDate`,`purchasePrice`,`salesPrice`,`consumerPrice`,`productID`,`description`) VALUES ( NULL,'2012-11-15 00:00:00','1000','1200','1500','1','qwqw');
INSERT INTO `testspring`.`pricing`(`id`,`priceDate`,`purchasePrice`,`salesPrice`,`consumerPrice`,`productID`,`description`) VALUES ( NULL,'2013-11-16 00:00:00',1500,1600,1500,1,'new price');

INSERT INTO `testspring`.`pricing`(`id`,`priceDate`,`purchasePrice`,`salesPrice`,`consumerPrice`,`productID`,`description`) VALUES ( NULL,'2012-10-15 00:00:00','1600','1500','1600','2','qwqw');
INSERT INTO `testspring`.`pricing`(`id`,`priceDate`,`purchasePrice`,`salesPrice`,`consumerPrice`,`productID`,`description`) VALUES ( NULL,'2013-11-02 00:00:00','1600','1900','3400','2','new price');

SELECT p.salesPrice FROM  pricing p INNER JOIN pricing pp ON p.productID = pp.productID AND p.priceDate>pp.priceDate 
WHERE p.description<>pp.description
```

Comment: what data you having in your priceDate column

Comment: Date for e.g. in the priceDate col has a data like this 2012-11-15 00:00:00

Comment: I appreciate your help,but it seems you did not understand my requirement. I have a col in my table which stores the date of the new price of the product. what I need is in my HQL to filter and get the latest price of the product

Comment: @ZAJ I can understand a bit, without comparing two dates or two price how it is possible to get latest one or you simply have to call the salesPrice in the query

Comment: please see my original post,i have added the full code. the thing is I need to send the productPricing object to the client. I need to filter out the old dates out

Comment: @ZAJ that is the sql I post, only sql is working give me some time I'll post the hql

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
String select = "SELECT p FROM  ProductPricing p where p.productId.supplierId.id=:id and p.priceDate = NOW()"; 
Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery(select);
query.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(dsRequest.getFieldValue("supplier").toString()));

List<ProductPricing> models = query.list();
```

Comment: please try execute a sample query using Date = NOW(); you won't get any result